# Prove theorem in clausal form.

Tags: logic

I'm working on an assignment to build a lisp program that will prove a theorem in clausal form. The program will take input (((A)(B C)) ((B)()) ((C)()))), the first n-1 sublist are the axioms and the nth sub list is the theorem to prove.

Although horrible inefficient can I simple generate all subsets of the axioms and resolve each one of those sets through resolution? If A contradiction is present I should be guaranteed to find it. Please let me know if my understanding is correct.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Comment: If using resolution, the first thing to do is to *negate* the conclusion, and add that to the set of premises (what you call axioms).

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor: Please don't bite newbies in that way, _especially_ not when there's nothing in their post that would be made more readable by using mathjax.

Comment: @HenningMakholm It’s just one of the generalized comments for which I have a shortcut saved. Would a $\ddot\smile$ help?

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor: Please confine your use of such generalized comments, with or without smileys, to questions that they actually are appropriate for.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if your set of clauses is inconsistent then, while horribly inefficient, trying all subsets for inconsistency (through the resolution method) will work.

However, a logically equivalent way of putting that is: while it will work, it will be horribly inefficient!

Yes, it is *possible* that some smaller subset is already inconsistent, but given as you'd do the same resolutions over and over, why not just start with the whole set of clauses? Because if the argument is valid, then that whole clause set (consisting of the clauses as generated by the premises together with the negation of the conclusion) will be inconsistent.